# Replace character in a df for numeric vector in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I would like to replace characters for specifics numeric vector.

I have this df:

```
First Second Third
 A      C      D
 F      R      K

and I also have vectors like these
A = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

R = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

N = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I have tried several times but I can't do it. Does anyone have some advice or idea?

Comment: Can you share what code you've tried?

Comment: this for example: df$`First`[df$`First`=="A"] <- A

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to `unlist` (convert to `character` if it is `factor`) and then use `mget` to return the values for that object in a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(as.character(unlist(df)))
```

Comment: I have used this q[q=="A"] <- list(A)
but what I need is a numeric vector per cell because I think the knn I am going to use require numeric vector.

Comment: @ManuelDominguezBecerra  You can just do `df[] <- mget(as.character(unlist(df)))`  where each element will be a `list`